# Can't create object from required module in Kotlinjs

Tags: javascript, kotlin, requirejs

As far as I know, you have to declare `require()` like this in kotlin:

```
external fun require(module: String): dynamic
```

#### Usage

```
val module = require("module")
```

But when using this, I came across this strange problem:

```
var myObject = module.SampleClass();
                      ^
TypeError: Class constructor SampleClass cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

Prepending the word `new` breaks the code. What should I do In this situation?

[Link to the object I tried to create](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client)

### UPDATE

When looking at the compiled javascript file I realized something.

The code I actually wrote

```
val myObject = module.SampleClass()
```

Compiled code

```
var myObject = module.SampleClass();
```

It makes sense, that this error is thrown when there's actually no `new` in front of the constructor call. Is there something like a keyword or function I should call in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there's a `js(code: String)` function. The right way to do this was to use call the constructor like this:

```
val client = js("new module.SampleClass();")
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining `require` function isnot the best way to work with modules in Kotlin.

Check out the [`@JsModule`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-modules.html#jsmodule-annotation) annotation and the [`external`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-interop.html#external-modifier) modifier. Using those two you can tell the compiler which module to `require` and how exactly the JS API of that module looks like.

In your case your code could look something like this:

```
// Module.kt
@file:JsModule("module")

package module

external class SomeClass() {}

// Main.kt
import module.SampleClass

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   val myObject = SampleClass()
}
```

Also check out https://github.com/kotlin/js-externals for external declaration examples and some useful links.

P.S. Don't forget to set the module kind to CommonJS (File -> Settings -> ...)